# Create a dot grid background using javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, grid

I would like to generate a dot grid background with javascript, WITHOUT using canvas or a repeating image; they just won't work for this use case.

I want to create a grid that I can snap elements to (I have this part figured out, there's plenty of examples out there) but I want that grid to be a dot grid and not a lined grid.  I would like the user to have the option to easily adjust the size of the grid. (20x20, 80x80, whatever they would like)

Does anyone have an example they are willing to share or maybe an explanation of the concept to point me in the right direction so I can research the right things?  My searching so far has come up very lacking.

Comment: How about, create a bunch of transparent divs as grid elements, inside each div create 4 span elements absolutely positioned on each corner, and set dot background to each span via CSS.

Comment: levi, thanks for the idea it got me thinking and it turns out that a simple radial gradient css background will get me at started. From here I can figure out how to overlay a grid, have elements snap to it,  and so on.  Here is the fiddle:   [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sphighend/fq7gA/2/)